# Bind to Application.ActualTheme in a ControlTemplate XAML UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I'm trying to create a control that uses a `RevealBorderBrush` as its border brush in XAML. I want to use the correct `TargetTheme` value for the brush, so I'm trying to bind to my application's current `ActualTheme` value. I'm using a templated control to do this. My C# code behind file is just the empty constructor that inherits from `Control` and sets the default style key. The following is my `Generic.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Plank">

<Style TargetType="local:PlankPL" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:PlankPL">
                <Border
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <RevealBorderBrush TargetTheme="{Binding Source=local:App, Path=ActualTheme}"/>
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I'm pretty sure the binding statement is incorrect, but I'm not sure how to write it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but it should work. Name your control then use the below code, replace ControlTemplateName with what you used.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t bind background data in ResourceDictionary, it doesn’t work.

It is recommended to write a UserControl and bind the RevealBorderBrush property of Border like following.

MyUserControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl..>
   <StackPanel>       
        <Border BorderThickness="3">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <RevealBorderBrush TargetTheme="{x:Bind theme1}"/>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
        </Border>
        <TextBox Text = "text demo text "/>
    </StackPanel>
    
</UserControl>
```

MyUserControl1.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl
    { 
        private  ApplicationTheme theme1;
        public MyUserControl1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            theme1 = Application.Current.RequestedTheme;
        }
    }
```